# IBM notes client plugin to modify outgoing mail

Tags: plugins, lotus-notes

I have been exploring plugin development for IBM notes.
I have downloaded expeditor toolkit, set up the dev environment, tried out simple plugin as described [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Video_Creating_Your_Fist_Eclipse_Plugin_For_Lotus_Notes)
Also I have gone through some openntf projects.

Now I am looking for ways to intercept outgoing mail so that some additional processing can be done, like encrypting attachments. 
Is it possible to intercept outgoing mail in notes client plugin?
Some examples/pointer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is more often done with plugins on the Domino server rather than with client-based code, but in either case intercepting mail messages can be done with the Extension Manager feature of the Notes [C API Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/toolkits.html). The technique involves hooking NSFNoteUpdate operations to the router mailbox, putting the message on hold so that the routing software will ignore it while the work is done, signaling a separate task to do the work, and then returning control to the client. Then the separate task can take whatever time is needed and then finally release the message from hold to allow the router to move the message.

I'm not sure if it would be possible to do something similar with the expeditor toolkit. It's operating at a higher level, so catching the message before the routing software kicks in may be a problem. It will also only handle manually submitted messages, whereas an Extension Manager solution will also catch messages sent by agents or standalone programs.

Comment: Currently I want to process the message at client side only. Processing only for manually submitted messages is ok for me.